# What is the best approach for insert duplicated key,value pairs and get them inserted order in java

Tags: java, collections, guava

I want to insert duplicated key, value and want to get them in inserted order what is the best solution for this in java collections?

Comment: List is what u are looking for

Comment: I want to insert them as key,value pairs. list can only contain keys

Comment: MultiMap is probably what u are looking for. http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: multiple keys that ar with multiple duplicate values for a key?

Comment: I tried with some multuMaps like LinkedHashMultimap but it want successful

Comment: Same key with different values

Comment: @LasithMalinga: Can you give some examples of what the output should look like for a given input?  Or what you did with `LinkedHashMultimap` that didn't give you the desired result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) will retain insertion order and they all allow duplicated elements.

> *An ordered collection (also known as a sequence). The user of this interface has precise control over where in the list each element is inserted.*

There are no `key-value` structures with these properties in standard Java, but Guava's [`LinkedListMultiMap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedListMultimap.html) might have what you are looking for.

> *An implementation of ListMultimap that supports deterministic iteration order for both keys and values. The iteration order is preserved across non-distinct key values.*

Comment: I want to insert them as key,value pairs. list can only contain keys

Comment: +1 for `LinkedListMultimap` being what the OP is looking for. `LinkedListMultimap.entries()` will get back all the entries in insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment I think that this is what u are looking for:

https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html

Answer (score 0):

Just create a helper class like this:

```
class KeyValuePair {
    public final Foo key;
    public final Bar value;

    public KeyValuePair(Foo key, Bar value) {
        this.key = key; this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And add this to any list you like.

Answer (score 0):

"multimap mapping from keys to multiple values"

as Keppil mentioned LinkedListMultimap is u wanted.

as i recommended u can try ImmutableListMultimap then invoke createValues to iterator the values(immutable* collection always get better peformance)